# Excel Conditional Formatting by Formula isn't applying correct styles

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a formula used for conditional formatting:

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(Primary,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2)))),ISNUMBER(FIND(Secondary,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2)))),INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),2))="ALL")
```

The formula is intended to highlight a cell if a value in the "B" column matches the value in the Primary field, the Secondary field, or is set to "ALL".

When pasted into any cell in a row, it returns the appropriate TRUE or FALSE value, however when used as a formula for conditional formatting, no cells receive any formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get rid of the indirect and ROW():

```
=OR(ISNUMBER(FIND(Primary,$B1)),ISNUMBER(FIND(Secondary,$B1)),$B1="ALL")
```

Make the sure the row refers to the first row in the Applies to: range.  So in this it is expeted that you are using full column reference or that the range starts on row 1.

If it is different then change the `1`s to the first row in the applies to range.